# How to run same application in new run tool window? Pycharm Community 2017

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, console-application

I am working on a Python 3.6 project in Pycharm Community Edition 2017.2.3.

I have multiple run configurations in my project. Each different run configuration will open a different ['Run tool window'](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-tool-window.html).

I want to look through the output of the previous run of my application while re-running it in another tool window. However, each new run of the same configuration will overwrite the console output of the previous run. How do I run the same application/configuration in a new tool window?

It's probably possible to just duplicate the [configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html), but I'm looking for a better way. Maybe something similar to [opening new terminals](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to build configurations and enable `show command line afterwards`.
It simply opens the python interpreter in the console after running your code.
Now When you run the code again. It will open a new tab in the run window, instead of overwriting the old one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can pin first tab by right click then run another script

Answer (score 1):

I do not think if it is possible. But you can do it using terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It's still in Run/Debug configurations but now it's called, "Run with Python console".